# How to create data import into several models in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new with Ruby and Rails framework (but I have good experience with PHP). So my question may look silly.

I have music database and several models like `Artist`, `Album` and `Song`.
Song belongs to `Artist` and `Album`. It's obvious.

My CSV looks like this:

```
Artist,Album,Song,Price,Url
"Roxette","Look Sharp!","Listen to Your Heart",1.99,"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roxette"
```

Song, Price, Url are stored inside `Song` model.

Data structure:

```
Artist
- id
- name

Album
- id
- name

Song
- artist_id
- album_id
- name
- price
- url
```

Models:

```
Artist
has_many :songs

Album
has_many :songs

Song
belongs_to :artist
belongs_to :album
```

I already found Roo and watched Railscasts about Roo. I can import data into one model. But I don't understand how to import data into 3 models at the same time and avoid duplicates.

Also, I would like to know, how to update price and url of songs, when the same songs will be uploaded again.

Please, explain or show how to deal with multi model data import.

*I apologize for bad grammar, English is not my native language.*

Comment: Can you describe your three models, and also is there any relationship between these three models?

Comment: Your question is little vague. What have you tried so far? What's the format of file you'll be using to import data? What will be the values of the columns `Artist,Album,Song,Price,Url`? Unless you provide detail we can not help you.

Comment: I added models etc. I'm not sure where to start it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Artist
  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs

class Album
  has_many :songs
  belongs_to :artist

class Song
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :song
```

when you iterate over the PDF...

```
artist = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: artist_name)
album = Album.find_or_create_by(name: album_name, artist_id: artist.id)
album.songs << song = Song.create(name: song_name, price: song_price, url: song_url)
album.save
artist.songs << song
artist.save
```